# Old 2008 MacBook Mac upgraded to OS X 10.9.5 from Snow Leopard to recycle without apple id password

Tags: hard-drive, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I want to pass along my 2008 MacBook on to a new user with the default factory settings. After erasing the MAC HD (without doing anything to the OS X Base system partition), I thought I would've been able to reinstall from disk utility (in recovery mode Command + R) the MAC OS.  But when I tried reinstalling it, it does not allow me to install on the disk that I erased.  It keeps asking for connection to the internet and for the **apple ID and password** which **we don't have** it belonged to our late father-in-law. I erased the 250.06 GB Macintosh HD with one pass.  There is a disk1 - OS X Base System which is considered a Recovery HD. I do have the Snow Leopard installation DVD but it won't install on the disk that I erased. During installation from the DVD it grays out the Recovery HD (OS X Base System) and it does not allow me to install on the erased MAC HD.  I don't know if I'm missing a step here. Given that its an old MacBook (late 2008) I just thought I wipe out the data and install the OS **without having the Apple ID and Password****.  Appreciate any Assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Will it boot from the DVD? This is by far your best bet on an old 2008.
2008s are not capable of Internet Recovery & can be tough to persuade to boot from USB.

Insert disk, restart, hold C at the chimes until you see an interface.

From there you should then be able to completely reformat the internal drive & install from the DVD. Once you have that done, you can then think about updating it to El Capitan.
Old Macs are not locked down in the same way as new ones, so this will completely remove any trace of the old owner accounts, passwords etc & allow it to be set up as a brand new machine. I'm assuming, as you managed to get so far, that there is no firmware password set.